# Java, pause thread execution while condition is not met

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

So I have and input thread, and a processing thread. The input thread takes files, parses them and put them in a JSON queue.

```
public class inputThread extends Thread {
 public void run() {
  for(File f: inputFiles){
    parse();
    App.processingQueue.add(f);
  }
}
```

Then the processing thread polls them, and processes them.

```
public class processingThread extends Thread {
  //Main loop
  while(!terminated){
    App.processingQueue.poll();
    process(...);  
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way to pause the input thread execution when queue.size() is greater than x? I looked up synchronized blocks and wait/sleep instructions, but I couldn't get any of them to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up semaphores. I like to use them at situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, use a BlockingQueue.   see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

then you have to use the blocking methods: put()  and take()

for example:

```
int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 10;
BlockingQueue<File> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(MAXIMUM_CAPACITY);
blockingQueue.put(   )
blockingQueue.take()
```